# How to send variable attribute Ids in XACML 3.0 Policy

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am creating a Policy in WSO2 Identity Server using WSO2 Management Console "Basic Policy Editor". I want to declare "resource-id" attribute as variable instead of a value. May I know how to declare that in "Basic Policy Editor " of WSO2 IS ?